# convert array to object type inside json object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to convert the below object

```
"site_permissions": {
      "70488413-6750-4f0b-8947-061a85c49e20": [
        "8e0bc18c-0387-49e2-99ea-a6359b60d54d",
        "a014a059-8d43-4337-830c-e2742627cf47",
        "4ec12e88-64eb-4b0d-bfc7-7a46f562cf93"
      ]
    }
```

to

```
"site_permissions": {
      "70488413-6750-4f0b-8947-061a85c49e20": {
        "8e0bc18c-0387-49e2-99ea-a6359b60d54d",
        "a014a059-8d43-4337-830c-e2742627cf47",
        "4ec12e88-64eb-4b0d-bfc7-7a46f562cf93"
      }
    }
```

is this possible if so how to do in n optimal way ?

Comment: Desired output is invalid.

Comment: no, it is not possible. you need keys and values.

Comment: BTW, please read [what is the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Since your desired output is invalid, you should maybe explain what you want to do with it. How would you access it in your code?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the object must-have key and value and if you want to convert it, will must to be as this way

```
"site_permissions": {
      "70488413-6750-4f0b-8947-061a85c49e20": {
        "8e0bc18c-0387-49e2-99ea-a6359b60d54d": 
        "8e0bc18c-0387-49e2-99ea-a6359b60d54d",

        "a014a059-8d43-4337-830c-e2742627cf47":
        "a014a059-8d43-4337-830c-e2742627cf47",

        "4ec12e88-64eb-4b0d-bfc7-7a46f562cf93":
        "4ec12e88-64eb-4b0d-bfc7-7a46f562cf93"
      }
    }
```

and you can use this code to make it

```
const site = {
    "70488413-6750-4f0b-8947-061a85c49e20": [
      "8e0bc18c-0387-49e2-99ea-a6359b60d54d",
      "a014a059-8d43-4337-830c-e2742627cf47",
      "4ec12e88-64eb-4b0d-bfc7-7a46f562cf93"
    ]
  };
  let newObject = {};
  Object.keys(site).map((key) =>{
    site[key].map((value) => 
    {
       newObject[value] = value;
    }
    );
    site[key] = newObject;
    newObject = {};
  });

  console.log(site);
```